# Issue with touchpad on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mouse, touchpad

I'm having a hard time on getting to work my laptop's touchpad. The problem emerged after I installed the packages to make Netflix works with Ubuntu. I followed this tutorial at [www.techtudo.com.br](http://www.techtudo.com.br/dicas-e-tutoriais/noticia/2012/11/aprenda-instalar-o-netflix-no-ubuntu.html) for the Netflix installation, and it installed a bunch of packages, including Wine, etc (the tutorial is in portuguese, but can be translated easily through Chrome).

After that, my laptop's touchpad stopped wornking. On my laptop's keyboard, there's a button that enables/disables the touchpad. What I realize is that, no matter how many times I push this button, it always returns to me a graphic notification showing that the touchpad is disabled.

If I run this command:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

The movement through the touchpad starts to working, but it still doesnt recover the toggle functionality of the touchpad blocking button on the keyboard.

Also, if I plug a USB mouse, the pointer movement works fine through the external mouse.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-quantal is the default driver for touchpad in ubuntu 12.04, see whether it is there or not. If it is not there then try

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-quantal

If it is there then try to reconfigure it with

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-quantal

If it states that it is not installable, then try to install the another version with

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

Before installing do sudo apt-get update

logout and log in back, might need restart...

Hope this helps..